# Returning the number of documents in solr when result set is grouped and the group is limited

Tags: solr

I am using grouping in solr to determine the number unique values in a specific column and the total number of documents for the query.  This number is returned using the `group.ngroup=true` method in the request.  This means the result returns `ngroup=30000` and `matches=500000`

This is good until the number of documents returned per group is limited (and the limit would be fixed). e.g If I were to pull all records (hypothetically I am not saying this will be done) from this result set each group would be limited to `group.limit=#`

If I am only returning two documents (`group.limit=2`) per group out of a possible range of documents per group of 1 to 20 this obviously means that the total number of documents returned for this select when limited is between `1*ngroup` and `2*ngroup`

The question is how do I return the exact number of documents returned based on group.limit? as opposed to the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, there doesn't seem to be an option to get the exact number of documents returned when we use grouping.

> The response field **"matches"** and **"numFound"** returns the number of docs
>   matched but not the number of docs returned in response as per
>   your limiting based on **group.limit** parameter.

This could be a "good to have" feature in forthcoming Solr releases.

Comment: Thank you - I don't suppose you know how I go about suggesting this feature to the solr crew?